# How can I see the hats I have earned across all of SE?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2012

Currently I need to go to Winterbash and click on each of the hats I have earned then manually count all the sites I have earned each one. This takes some time, and I don't have that many fingers and toes.

Can we have a view which gives the number of each hat earned?

Comment: I don't think there's currently a way to do it directly, but I plan on writing a Greasemonkey script along these lines when I get home tonight.

Comment: @Polynomial it would be better if we could have this… If Stackoverflow provided it.

Comment: @kmkaplan It would be, but I'll write something up anyway ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As promised, I've [written a Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/154512) to do this.

[image: Hat summary]

On the [front page of Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/), you'll see a small box saying "detailed list". Clicking on this begins the loading process, which involves an Ajax call per hat. From there you'll get a nice list of hats, with a list of sites you've unlocked the hat on and a total count.

Features:

- Simple code, should be easy to modify.
- Loading via ajax, with loading percentage shown.
- Works with all hats displayed on the page. If you unlock any "super secret" hats, it should include those too.
- Creative Commons licensed.

This has been tested on Firefox, but may also work on Chrome. If you run into any bugs or have any other ideas, let me know!

---

**Version 1.11 released**

- Removed stupid debug text from page that I forgot to remove on release.

**Version 1.10 released**

- Replaced spans with a table.
- Fixed wrapping issue when a badge was earned on a large numbers of sites (thanks Gilles!)
- Added a trick with text-indent and padding to keep left align relatively neat.
- Added mouse-over highlighting to rows.

Comment: dude - this rocks!

Comment: Well I have to find *something* to do with my evenings!

Comment: This is arguably more useful than my WInter Bash userscript :-D

Comment: @TheUnhandledException Arguably? *Indubitably*. :P

Comment: Upvoted. Though I’d still rather have Stack Exchange provide the functionnality.

Comment: I have tested it on Chrome, and it works, but sometimes you need to navigate away from Winterbash and come back to it, especially if you have more than one tab open with winterbash

Comment: Nice. On Chrome (I haven't tried Firefox), the alignment is all wonky when the list of sites exceeds the available horizontal space: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tPc7T.png

Comment: @Gilles Yup, that'll happen if you end up with lots of sites on one line. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Gilles Fixed, and I've added a few improvements too.

Comment: Thanks. You forgot to remove “Testing 1, Testing 2”.

Comment: Haha, whoops! Will remove them.