# Are we going to have statistics when Winter Bash is over, or will it just vanish into thin air?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2012

Winter Bash seem to attract lots of attention and I see many users wearing all kinds of hats. When it's over, the hats will of course disappear however I think that adding usage statistics to the [official blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/) will be a good thing just to... well, just to have statistics.

I'm not talking about adding live stats like already asked before, but rather adding this after there are no more hats so that we can reflect on that and tell our friends "See, we were part of this!".

Nay or yay?

I would like to see the following information:

- Total hats received all across the network. (Just plain grand sum)
- Total hats being actively worn all across the network: grand sum and maybe even how many of each type and for  how long. (Kind of "popularity meter")
- Leaderboard showing all sites with more than 100 hats and top 10 users on each of those.

Comment: If it is Nay then I want it as feature-request.

Comment: Winter Bash will never go away.  We may lose out hats, but the mere existence of WB-related questions on MSO guarantees a steady future stream of questions like "What was Winter Bash", "Why did it stop" and "Is it coming back"... Just like a stench that lingers

Comment: @Chris nope. I'm pretty sure that all questions related to the winter bash will be deleted, only the blog post and maybe selected few related discussions will stay.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My plans do include a wrap-up memo or blog post or commemorative meta post. If there's information you'd like for me to include in that thing, feel free to let me know!

Otherwise: yes, I intend to make sure us quantitative types have all the quant data our hearts could desire in one handy blog post! :)

Comment: Thanks, added the information I'm interested in to my question above. :)

Comment: One piece of data I would really like to see is the breakdown by site of the hats tied to a particular date (I Feel Fine, L'chaim, New Year's Eve Hat...).

Comment: Include number of hats gathered of each type. Number of users that gathered most/all hats, including graphs!

Comment: Stats! Lots of stats everywhere please! With graphs and charts all that too for added fun.

Comment: A list of what all the hidden hats were! :)

Comment: A lit of the top 3 hat collectors on each of the major sites!

Comment: Would also like to see stats for all SE, not just per site (eg top hat collecters SE-wide leaderboard)...that's top 'hat collectors' btw, not 'top hat' collectors.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Yeah, nice idea. That'll show who has been the most active all across SE, rather than those that have been very active on just one or two sites. Has anyone hit triple-figures for overall hats?

Comment: Yep - I've got over 130 :-)

Comment: @JonW - you can use this to check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159381/154443

Comment: @Aarthi -- Where might these stats be? ^_^

Comment: @amanaplan I need a few days! Regressions are hard!

Comment: @Aarthi baaah :-P

Comment: Looks like [the blog post is ready](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/boxing-day/)! :)

Answer (score 2):

Today, I used the Easter Egg in the top banner of the [winterba.sh](http://winterba.sh/) web-site as a demonstration that you could include a little bit of whimsy and humour in a site, without having to make it brash or distracting.

Comment: Nice, but guess you meant to write this answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161331/the-quest-for-the-winter-unicorn-of-the-bash), if it wasn't closed?

Comment: No, not referring to the unicorn. The more obvious one - it isn't deeply hidden.

Comment: Oh, the Stack Exchange logo?