# Add Winterbash and other special event results to user profile page in perpetuity

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, winter-bash-2012

Since they plan on doing specials like Winterbash in the future, maybe they could add a section on the profile for `Legacy Awards` or something like that, that will show the temporary awards earned in the past.

For Winterbash, they'd just have the title Winterbash in that section with the pics of the hats.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160334/are-we-going-to-have-statistics-when-winter-bash-is-over-or-will-it-just-vanish)

Comment: Only if you can make it visible to only 20K+ rep users.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea, but I don't agree with it:

1. **It's almost over.** I hate to admit it, but the Winter Bash is almost over, and there will be no more hats. That said, maybe next year, but I still don't agree with it.
2. **Wouldn't that just be like badges?** If you have pictures of the hats on your profile, wouldn't that be the same thing as badges except that somebody who doesn't have a hat can't earn them until next year? I mean, that's what badges are: pictures on your profile that you get because you did something on the site.
3. **Some people didn't want hats.** For those who didn't want hats (pressed "i hate hats"), they have nothing to show. Plus, the "i hate hats" option turned off their ability to *view* hats, so you would have to make that option available forever for people who hate hats.

So basically, good idea but it's kind of pointless.

Comment: I'm assuming that if they do hats next year, they'll be different, and they might do something completely different.  I would think they would just put pngs of the hats, so all could see them.  mostly, I would have it a few clicks into the profile, so it has to be somebody wanting to see it.  But hey, I'm not saying there's much point to it, just a bonus for those of us who participated.

Comment: +1, the whole point of the hats, as I see it, is that they're only temporary.  Make them permanent, and they're just funny-looking badges.  (I do support the idea of recording the information _somewhere_ for the sake of future curiosity / ego-boosting.  Maybe make a data dump available for download or something.  It just shouldn't be anywhere on the profile.)

Comment: @LanceRoberts Why don't you put the pictures in your profile bio? This way you can see your hats, but not have to worry about SE making a section for them.